# Website erroring in IE6 only, all other browsers fine

Tags: php, debian, wordpress, internet-explorer

I was just trying to check out one of my websites on IE6, and I receive an error saying "Internet Explorer cannot open the Internet site... Operation Aborted".

Now it turns out that when I try the same site on Firefox on the same machine (VirtualBox WinXP VM) it works. Other websites I host on the same machine also work in IE6, so it's not like the box is unreachable. In fact, my server logs show a 200 status that the page was reached.

If it matters, I'm running WordPress for the site, so I think it could be a PHP thing at this point. However, my other WordPress site on the same box (which is Debian Lenny, btw) loads just fine. So weird.

Many thanks for any help.

UPDATE: Just replaced home page with static HTML and it loaded. Looks like it could a PHP issue. Is it possible there is some difference in how IE6 acts with PHP as opposed to other IE versions?

UPDATE 2: I'm on WP 2.9.1 and have disabled all of my plugins. Interestingly, I see the title of the site for a brief time for the error pops up. Does that pretty much confirm that it's PHP related? I'm using PHP 5 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue fixed. Problem is that you cannot write to the HEAD HTML element before it is closed, caused by my moving my asynchronous Google Analytics script there.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917

Comment: There's a discussion on the IE Blog about how this was *partially* fixed in IE8 http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check proxy settings of IE6, it may be using some random proxy.

Also, it goes without saying, you should probably move away from IE6, offer a JS pop up that alerts the user to upgrade their browser.

Comment: Hmm, nothing on the proxy front. Thanks, though. 

Realistically I'd love to just deny my users outright (got my wish I guess), but I'd rather do it on purpose ;).

Comment: can you access any other sites in 6? What about your webserver logs, do they show unusal issues? What technology is the site built in, if it's a dynamic language (Ruby, PHP, .NET, etc) you should be able to get some verbosity in the output and write it to a log to see why it's failing.

Comment: That's the odd thing. The access log shows a 200 OK and nothing in the error log. The site is built in PHP (Wordpress). 

I'll turn up my log level to DEBUG and see if that helps.

Comment: PHP shouldn't matter to IE6 as a language. PHP simply outputs rendered HTML to the browser.

HOWEVER!!! It may be sending a location header ("header("Location:<some other place>");) that is incorrect, causing IE6 to route somewhere it doesn't like. This would usually manifest itself in the other browsers as well though. Do you have a URL that we can look at and examine?

Comment: Turns out I was an idiot and the problem was Javascript. I appreciate your dialog though :) Thank you.